# Crontab not running on sunday night

Tags: cron

So I made this so it would send a command at Sunday night at 11:59pm, 1 minute before Monday, but for some reason it doesn't work. I even changed the `* * 7` to `0`.

```
59 23 * * 7 screen -S skyblock -p 0 -X stuff "mangdelp default essentials.fly ${printf \\r)"
```

Comment: Well, did it work ? Please accept the answer if it helped you :)

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is incorrect.

It should be like this:

```
59 23 * * 0 screen -S skyblock -p 0 -X stuff \"mangdelp default essentials.fly ${printf \\r)\" >/dev/null 2>&1
```

> ```
> minute(s) hour(s) day(s) month(s) weekday(s) command(s)
> ```
>
> The fields are
>   separated by spaces or tabs. The first five are integer patterns and
>   the sixth is the command to be executed. The following table briefly
>   describes each of the fields.
>
> Field Value   Description
>
> minute    0-59    The exact minute that the command sequence executes
>
> hour   0-23    The hour of the day that the command
>   sequence executes
>
> day    1-31    The day of the month that the command
>   sequence executes
>
> month    1-12  The month of the year that the command
>   sequence executes
>
> weekday    0-6 The day of the week that the command
>   sequence executes. Sunday=0, Monday = 1, Tuesday = 2, and so forth.
>
> command    Special The complete sequence of commands to be executed. The
>   command string must conform to Bourne shell syntax. Commands,
>   executables (such as scripts), or combinations are acceptable.

Comment: awesome ill let you know if it works next sunday 8) ha

Comment: Please also verify that `screen -S skyblock -p 0 -X stuff \"mangdelp default essentials.fly ${printf \\r)\" >/dev/null 2>&1` actually works and returns the expected behaviour